# Default tablespace for indexes in postgres

Tags: postgresql, django-models

Just wondering if its possible to set a default tablespace in postgres to keep indexes.  Would like the databases to live on the default tablespace for postgres, however, would like to get the indexes on a different set of disks just to keep the i/o traffic separated.

It does not appear to me that it can be done without going in and doing an ALTER index TABLESPACE command, and then the index is moved and will stay there, but the databases and indexes are part of a django app, so non-django intervention can cause some problems.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a way to specify a default index tablespace (that is other than the database's own default tablespace). I've always specified them manually. It's fairly easy to write a query to check for indices that are in the wrong tablespace, so you could at least install that as part of your database monitoring.

IMHO you shouldn't have to be worried about making changes like that to the database outside of the app since it's a database implementation detail the app doesn't grok. If the app has a problem with it, the app is broken.

Comment: As best as I can tell, Django doesn't even properly use the setting for the per-Model tablespace or DEFAULT_TABLESPACE setting on postgresql.  Only the Oracle backend seems to generate anything via tablespace_sql.

Answer (score 0):

Currently django supports default tablespace for database and for [indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE):

DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
Default: '' (Empty string)

Default tablespace to use for indexes on fields that don't specify one, if the backend supports it.

DEFAULT_TABLESPACE
Default: '' (Empty string)

Default tablespace to use for models that don't specify one, if the backend supports it.

Comment: If you read the code, it doesn't look like the postgresql and postgresql_psycopg2 backends actually generate the proper SQL to append the tablespace.  For example, there's no definition of tablespace_sql in either of these backends, so it uses the default one, which only generates ''.

Comment: worked for me. I had to patch my django 1.2 for it to work. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12308

Comment: "worked for me" and "had to patch django" are two totally different things.